# How to calculate averages of particular set of intervals in an arraylist?

Tags: c#, arraylist, average, intervals

I'm trying to identify values that are greater than 200 in an array-list and calculate averages of these values for each interval. My array-list is,

```
List<int> numlist = new List<int>();
```

and it contains values,

```
numlist.Add(50);
numlist.Add(67);
numlist.Add(98);
numlist.Add(150);
numlist.Add(230);
numlist.Add(250);
numlist.Add(260);
numlist.Add(87);
numlist.Add(98);
numlist.Add(201);
numlist.Add(254);
numlist.Add(164);
```

As you can see, the first set of consecutive  values that are greater than 200 is 230,250 and 260. The second set of values are 201 and 254.

I want to loop through the array-list and identify these two sets separately and then calculate their averages.

average 1: (230 + 250 + 260)/3

average 2: (201 + 254)/2

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should achieve what you want, it will produce another list containing all the averaged values of consecutive numList entries over 200 (but not equal to 200!);

```
        var sum = 0;
        var count = 0;
        var averages = new List<double>();
        foreach (var t in numlist)
        {
            if (t > 200)
            {
                sum += t;
                count += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                if (sum == 0) continue;
                var average = (double) sum/count;
                averages.Add(average);
                sum = 0;
                count = 0;
            }
        }
```

Comment: can you explain what,  if (sum == 0) continue; does

Comment: this is the code that decides whether you have reached a new sequence of code over 200. If sum is 0 then you haven't started a new average and so it skips everything that follows and moves to the next value in numlist